# How to scrub personal information from an xcode project?

Tags: xcode, macos

I would like to upload an iOS project to github (*or basically anywhere*) but before I do that, I'd like to know if there is an automated process or someway to export the project by scrubbing all/any personal information from the project such as:

1. Name & Organization details (*from the class files as well*)
2. Profile information
3. Any other bits of potentially "*personal*" information (*that I haven't mentioned*)

Comment: You'd probably have to use `sed` from the command line.

Comment: Remark: There are also per-user subdirectories that contain your name, such as `./project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/<user>.xcuserdatad`, `./xcuserdata/<user>.xcuserdatad` ...

Comment: @trojanfoe : ok, that's a nice way to remove specified information from within class files or any file basically

Comment: @MartinR : yes, that too! thanks for reminding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>So... all I had asked was to upload a project to GitHub or anywhere with minimal (*preferably none*) personal information.</sub>

### For GitHub:

I created a file called `.gitignore` and have the following contents in it (*specifically in context with the question*)

> #Xcode
>
> xcuserdata
>   *.xcworkspace

This ignores the mentioned files/folders during a commit.
*<sub>I should have read about Git earlier but anyways...</sub>*

---

### Whereas... normally

When I share/manually upload a project, I just delete the following folders before uploading to, say, dropbox:

1. `~.xcodeproj/xcuserdata`
2. `~.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace`

<sup>*PS: These files and folders return when you open the project again.*</sup>

---

### Furthermore

*An irritating step ahead...*

To prevent my Mac username from being auto-filled in the default comments (*you know... alongwith the boiler plate code*), I just went ahead and edited the default Xcode File Templates (*since I am a bit crazy*)

The templates are located here:

1. iOS templates

   - `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Cocoa Touch/`
2. OSX templates

   - `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/`

<sup>**Note:** the `.h` and `.m` templates are nested inside</sup>

Change the **`___FULLUSERNAME___`** (*and maybe the **`___COPYRIGHT___`***) parameter to something... static ;P

> Original template should look like this:
>  
>  
>
>  //
>  //  ___FILENAME___
>  //  ___PROJECTNAME___
>  //
>  // 
>  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
>  //___COPYRIGHT___
>  //

<sub>PS: Make a backup of the modified templates... incase Apple resets them to the default template</sub>

---

Lastly... I just ensure I don't enter any personal information anywhere *<sup>(yeah.... totally lame)</sup>*